# How to extract strings from a webelement using regex in a list (python)

Tags: python, regex, string, selenium

I'm having trouble to extract specific set of words in a webelement and assigning it to a list. My webelement.

My webelement.text looks like:

```
Accountant Johnathan Christensen <br>
President<br>
Accountant Annete Benning<br>
Vice President
```

And I need it to be inserted in a list, that should looks like:

```
list[['Johnathan Christensen','President']
     ['Annete Bening', 'Vice-President']]**
```

I'm getting an empty result using this code within a loop:

```
list.append(re.findall(r"^vice-president (.*)",col.text))
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re

text = '''Accountant Johnathan Christensen <br>
President<br>
Accountant Annete Benning<br>
Vice President
'''

result = [list(i) for i in re.findall(r'^Accountant\s+(.+?)(?:(?:\s*<br>)?\n)(.+?)(?:(?:\s*<br>)?\n)', text, re.M)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['Johnathan Christensen', 'President'], ['Annete Benning', 'Vice President']]
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `^Accountant\s+` matches the substring at the beginning of the line.
- `(.+?)` matches a substring between above pattern and below pattern
  assiging the group1 to the match.
- `(?:(?:\s*<br>)?\n)` matches the end of the line preceded by the
  optional `<br>` tag.
- `(.+?)` matches a substring between above pattern and below pattern
  assiging the group1 to the match.
- `(?:(?:\s*<br>)?\n)` matches the end of the line preceded by the
  optional `<br>` tag string.
- The next `(.+?)` matches the following substring (possibly the title)
  assiging the group2 to the match
- The final `(?:(?:\s*<br>)?\n)` matches the end of the line preceded by the
  optional `<br>` tag string.
- The `re.M` option makes `^` and `$` match to the start or end of any
  line within the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it without regex, bellow is the example.

```py
items = []
text = '''Accountant Johnathan Christensen <br>
President<br>
Accountant Annete Benning<br>
Vice President'''
split = text.split('<br>')
for i in range(0,len(split),2):
    temp = [str(x).strip().strip('Accountant').strip() for x in split[i:i+2]]
    items.append(temp)
print(items)
```

You will get this output:

```
[['Johnathan Christense', 'Preside'], ['Annete Benning', 'Vice Preside']]
```